# How do I fix these polygon artifacts in a Nintendo 64 emulator using the parallel plugin on libretro

Tags: emulation, nintendo-64, super-mario-64, retroarch, mario-golf-64

I am having trouble with polygons drawing incorrectly. On Mario's feet there are dark polgons drawn around the edges. In Mario Golf 64, there are overlapping polgons. It looks like a z-sorting issue. I don't see any options to address this issue in retroarch or in the parallel plugin options.

I can't find anyone having this problem. I have tinkered with settings and gone back to defaults. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you explain the problem? I, for one, can't see a problem. Others might not even be able to view your images; questions need to be able to stand on their own, without images.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't even attempt a description. The one in Mario 64 is really hard to notice with a still image. His feet should not have that dark outline. In Mario Golf I think it is more noticeable. Look at his waste and his pants. In that picture it looks like his fly is open because of the awkward polygon rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The artifacts you refer to appear to be present when playing the games on physical Nintendo 64 consoles.

There is nothing wrong with the emulator; it is simply doing its job.

---

To answer this question, I simply went and looked at other playthroughs of the games.

First, we have "Super Mario 64". This was an easy one to find - I just looked up a "Games Done Quick" video to find a version being played on the Super Nintendo 64. I can clearly see the same dark polygons drawn around the edge of Mario's feet. I note that they are not always seen - I notice they disappear in the water level. I assume the polygons are being drawn that way based off the lighting, but in the example scene you show, the original console draws them in the same way.

[image: "Super Mario 64" shown on a Nintendo 64 at GDQ 2018 shows the same "artifacts".]

Secondly, we have "Mario Golf 64". I found it impossible to find a verified playthrough of this on an actual Nintendo 64 console, let alone specifically as the character Charlie shown in the original screenshot. However, literally everywhere I go, screenshots with Charlie as the main character show the exact same overlapping polygons. I assume this was simply a developer error.

[image: "Mario Golf 64", playing as Charlie, shows the same "artifacts" no matter where you look for screenshots or gameplay videos.]

Comment: After work I will hook up my N64 and check. I never considered these artifacts to be legit, but your images don't lie. I will report back.

Comment: I just fired up Mario 64 on my N64 on a big screen with s-video. I never noticed this artifact before but it is very visible. I can't unsee it now :*(

The emulator is working perfectly then, I was mistaken!